# Extend table columns to full width with auto height scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to extend the columns in a table to full width, with auto height functionality when it overflows the max height. I have a width constraint for each column as shown in the example, Can someone suggest the fix if I would like to keep both the functionalities

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vakshu/p9knfd5z/1/)

If I use `display:block` I cant extend the width of the columns till end(**blue color table**), and if I remove I cant use the auto scroll property, it just displays everything without considering the maximum height constraint(**orange color table**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to turn a table into a block element, its a table element. Instead use wrappers (no don't actually stick your candy bar wrappers to the screen).

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9knfd5z/3/))

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <table class="tabHeight1">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey2</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey3</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey4</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey5</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey6</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey7</td>
            <td class="tdwidth">hey1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    max-height: 100px!important;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.tabHeight1 {
    width:100%;
    padding:2px;
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to do this by wrapping the table into a DIV tag. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/p9knfd5z/5/

I took display:block out of the table... See divstyle for DIV that wraps the table.

```
.divstyle {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Yeah there is not need for making the surrounding div block element... I took it out. Still works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/p9knfd5z/5/ good answer above. thanks @humble.rumble.6x3

Comment: I am on chrome... it looks great. what do you see that does not look good?